# Why does the algorithm shortestpathpointtopoint in QGIS3 using pyqgis only work in the second run?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, qgis-3

A part of my skript uses the shortestpathpointtopoint algorithm, but it does only work in the second run (Python Console within QGIS). The discussed part of the script looks like

```
points_lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(u'cabinets')[0]
network_lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(u'pipes')[0]

for f in points_lyr.getFeatures():
    if f.attribute('Art') == 2:
        pStart = QgsPointXY(f.geometry().asPoint().x(),f.geometry().asPoint().y())
    elif f.attribute('Art') == 4:
        pStop = QgsPointXY(f.geometry().asPoint().x(),f.geometry().asPoint().y())

print('Start: ', pStart)
print('Stop: ', pStop)

parameters = {'INPUT': network_lyr,
                'STRATEGY': 0,
                'DIRECTION_FIELD': '',
                'VALUE_FORWARD': '',
                'VALUE_BACKWARD': '',
                'VALUE_BOTH': '',
                'DEFAULT_DIRECTION': 2,
                'SPEED_FIELD': '',
                'DEFAULT_SPEED': 1,
                'TOLERANCE': 0,
                'START_POINT': pStart,
                'END_POINT': pStop,
                'OUTPUT': 'memory:'}

my_line = processing.run('qgis:shortestpathpointtopoint', parameters)
```

This works perfectly, but only in the second run. In the first run I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
>       exec(code, self.locals)   File "", line 1, in    File "", line 37, in    File
>   "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py",
>   line 96, in run
>       return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)   File
>   "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py",
>   line 139, in runAlgorithm
>       raise QgsProcessingException(msg)
>   _core.QgsProcessingException: Unable to execute algorithm Incorrect parameter value for START_POINT

The prints of start&stop work in the first run. I don't get what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: are start and stop actually the same in each run?

Comment: Yes, I reduced the layer to two points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying another input-type, it worked

```
for f in points_lyr.getFeatures():
    if f.attribute('Art') == 2:
        #pStart = QgsPointXY(f.geometry().asPoint().x(), f.geometry().asPoint().y())
        pStart = str(f.geometry().asPoint().x()) + ',' + str(f.geometry().asPoint().y())
    else:
        continue

for f in points_lyr.getFeatures():
    if f.attribute('Art') == 4:
        #pStop = QgsPointXY(f.geometry().asPoint().x(), f.geometry().asPoint().y())
        pStop = str(f.geometry().asPoint().x()) + ',' + str(f.geometry().asPoint().y())

parameters = {'INPUT': network_lyr,
                'STRATEGY': 0,
                'DIRECTION_FIELD': '',
                'VALUE_FORWARD': '',
                'VALUE_BACKWARD': '',
                'VALUE_BOTH': '',
                'DEFAULT_DIRECTION': 2,
                'SPEED_FIELD': '',
                'DEFAULT_SPEED': 1,
                'TOLERANCE': 0,
                'START_POINT': pStart,
                'END_POINT': pStop,
                'OUTPUT': 'memory:'}
```

So it does not work in the first run, when I use QgsPointXY, but it works when the input is a string. Don't know why, but I can work with strings as well.